# search xml tag value with spaces in shellscript

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to find Name values enclosed in xml tags using awk, I can ind the values if it's 1 string but when there are spaces awk splits every word as new record.
Also my xml does not have line breaks.

My input file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet href="catalog.xsl" type="text/xsl"?><type><retail><custdata><Nm>John Smith</Nm><pstaddr1>10 north block</pstaddr1><pstaddr2>boeard st.</pstaddr2><ctry>HR</ctry></custdata><custdata><Nm>Jeff Blanks</Nm><pstaddr1>263 Jef. St.</pstaddr1><pstaddr2>3rd Avenue</pstaddr2><ctry>HR</ctry></custdata></retail><corporate></corporate></type>
```

I am trying to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
    for a in $(ls /usr/cycle1/sample/*.dat)
        do
        for c in $(awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[<>]";RS="</";  }; /Nm/{ print $2; }' "$a")
        do
        echo  $c
        done
    done
```

Output I am getting is:

```
John
Smith
Jeff
Blanks
```

Instead of

```
John Smith
Jeff Blanks
```

I might be doing something wrong with record separator but since I am new to awk not sure what is exact problem. Could you pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ed and Charles I used combined approach and simple AWK That works for me is. it is also worked very efficiently

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="<pstaddr1>"; FS="[<>]";}; /Nm/{ print $2 }' /usr/cycle1/sample/*.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tools such as `awk` to parse XML at all -- use a real XML parser. In this case, XMLStarlet:

```
for f in "/usr/cycle1/sample/"*.dat; do
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//Nm' -v . -n <"$f"
done
```

If you have a version with `--xpath` installed, you might also consider using `xmllint`:

```
for f in "/usr/cycle1/sample/"*.dat; do
  xmllint --xpath '//Nm' <"$f"
done
```

The naive approach can't correctly parse comments; can't correctly parse strings with special characters represented with entity escaping; can't correctly parse CDATA sections... or, to put it more bluntly, "can't correctly parse XML".

---

That said, to just fix the bash bugs in your existing code, and leave the XML-parsing bugs alone:

```
for a in "/usr/cycle1/sample/"*.dat; do
  while IFS= read -r name; do
    echo "$name"
  done < <(awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[<>]";RS="</";  }; /Nm/{ print $2; }' "$a")
done
```

To explain:

- `echo $name` is buggy: It string-splits each component of `$name` into a separate word, glob-expands each word, and passes each glob expansion result as a separate argument to `echo`. Instead, use `echo "$name"` to keep words together.
- `for file in $(ls /path/to/*.dat)` is buggy. In addition to breaking with filenames which can be interpreted as glob expressions and filenames containing characters in IFS, it also relies on poorly-defined behavior around how `ls` handles filenames containing unprintable characters. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for more details.
- `for c in $(awk ...)` is buggy, when what you want to do is read individual *lines* from `awk`. First, it splits awk content by characters in IFS, which includes other kinds of whitespace by default. However, even if you fixed this by reassigning IFS, it would also have bugs around glob expansion, and be needlessly memory-inefficient. Follow [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for best practices around reading from streams, and also see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

---

Finally: Here's an approach that "works" (with all the usual can't-parse-XML-with-regular-expressions caveats) in native bash:

```
re='[<]Nm[>]([^<>]+)[<][/]Nm[>](.*)'
for f in "/usr/cycle1/sample/"*.dat; do
  content=$(<"$f")
  while [[ $content =~ $re ]]; do
    printf '%q\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    content=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  done
done
```

---

Alternately, a memory-efficient variant -- again, not a real XML parser, and with serious limitations on input handled due to same.

```
for f in "/usr/cycle1/sample/"*.dat; do
  next=0
  while IFS= read -r content; do
    if (( next )); then
      printf '%s\n' "$content"
      next=0
      continue
    fi
    case $content in
      Nm) next=1; continue ;;
      *) continue ;;
    esac
  done < <(tr '[<>]' '\n' < "$f")
done
```

Comment: I agree with you and xmlstarlet was my preference but it's production server and I have limited options. Unfortunately I can not get it install due to all red tape.

Comment: That's why I also gave an answer that fixes the bash surrounding your awk.

Comment: ...however, if (as it appears) the awk is also buggy, that calls for something a bit different.

Comment: See the native-bash solution now amended.

Comment: Thanks i tried both native solution and while IFS option they both result in 'No Space' error. my input files are large (about 120 MB) and they are single line stream they don't have line breaks. i guess that's the reason why it results in error and reading line by line is not option for me.

Comment: @aj1981, the native solution certainly does output spaces when used with the input you provided. See it running at http://ideone.com/jMA1Gf -- if you want us to fix a problem, you have to provide means to duplicate it.

Comment: @aj1981, ...and the `while read` approach is actually much more memory efficient with large files than the `for x in $(...)` approach is.

Comment: @aj1981, ...wait, by "no space", do you mean no spaces in the output, or insufficient memory available to allocate?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy given the OPs comment about his input files being large, I suspect he's saying hes getting a memory error.

Comment: @aj1981, see yet another version available, this one optimized to be memory-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input files are always so regular, this might be all you need:

```
$ awk -v RS='<\\/?Nm>' '!(FNR%2)' file
John Smith
Jeff Blanks
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS which I assume is fine since you're already using that functionality in the example you posted.

Never do `for a in $(ls /usr/cycle1/sample/*.dat)` - you'd use `for a in /usr/cycle1/sample/*.dat` instead but you do not need that loop at all since awk can open multiple files:

```
awk -v RS='<\\/?Nm>' '!(FNR%2)' /usr/cycle1/sample/*.dat
```

If for some reason you need a shell variable set to the awk output (which is almost certainly a sign you are going to do something very bad in the rest of your script!) you could do:

```
$ IFS=$'\n' array=( $(awk -v RS='<\\/?Nm>' '!(FNR%2)' file) )
$ echo "${array[0]}"
John Smith
$ echo "${array[1]}"
Jeff Blanks
```

or various other things...

If you don't have GNU tools and you can't read the whole single-line file into awk at once due to memory constraints, you can mimic the above with:

```
$ sed -e 's/<Nm>/\
/g' -e 's/<\/Nm>/\
/g' file |
awk '!(NR%2)'
John Smith
Jeff Blanks
```